# Chrome Extension setTimeout and Messaging

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create (or rather learn) Chrome extension development. I am trying to achieve a simple task between popup and background pages. So far, I have the pages in place and popup can send message to background and background page replies. I am currently lost in creating the behavior I want:

- Have popup send a number to background page
- Have background page run during the duration of that number
- When the countdown is done, return the message the popup at the time of completion.

At this point, the background process sends the response immediately and I am sure I am not doing it right. Here is some code

Popup:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
method: "popup",
message: "remindMe",
now: parseInt(localStorage.timeNow),
timeToRemindIn: 5
 },

  function(response) {
    console.log("sendMessage");
console.log(response.farewell);
//alert(response.farewell);
console.log("sendMessage after");
```

Background:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        //console.log(sender.tab ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url : "from the extension");

        if (request.message == "remindMe") {
            startTime();
            if(localStorage.timeToRemindIn > now) {
                sendResponse({farewell: "reminder to check"});
            }
        } else {
            sendResponse({farewell: "hai hai"});
        }
     });

    function startTime() {
        now = parseInt(now) + 1;
        if(localStorage.timeToRemindIn > now) {
            console.log("Reminder to check this tab Yo! " + now);
            return;
        }
        if (localStorage.timeToRemindIn <= now) {
            timerId = window.setTimeout(startTime, pollInterval);
        }
    }
```

});

Comment: I'm surprised that you didn't get any errors, because `now` is not declared. The minimum requirement to get your code to work is `now = 1`, at the top of your listener. That may solve the problem, but not the bad code design: Because of a global variable, the extension can only handle one request at a time. A better solution is to use the return value of `startTime()`, and pass the initial time to `startTime`.

Comment: Thanks @RobW I accidentally missed that here but its in the code. Still does not work. I will make changes to the other suggestion of using the return valye of startTime().

Answer (score 0):

`startTime()` will not halt execution in any way, the setTimeout call is asynchronous so that function will instantly return and so the message will always be instantly sent back.

You need to refactor so that the `sendResponse` call is made from inside the function given to `setTimeout`.

Comment: If I have to make the `sendResponse` from inside a funtion, does that mean that function should contain `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener()` block. Now, should that be executed every second or so to keep listening to a call from popup? Say something like : `<body onload="startTime()">`